# Run ruby IRB for Ruby on rails from Aptana studio and/or radrails?

Tags: ruby, aptana, irb, radrails

I was a happy Ruby on Netbeans (6.9) user until I learned that NB (Oracle) will no longer be supporting Ruby, in future releases.  So, I'm trying out Aptana w RadRails plugin. so far the trasition has been a little tricky, but it seems okay.  BUT, I haven't figgured out how to Run ruby IRB for Ruby on rails from Aptana  studio and/or radrails.  I've been using version 2.05 of Aptana. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Very similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598888/creating-plain-rb-files-with-aptana-radrails

Comment: You should give Studio 3 a try.  http://aptana.com/products/studio3.  It has excellent Ruby support.

Answer (score 1):

As the lead developer of RadRails, I'd suggest upgrading to Studio 3 and using irb inside the embedded Terminal. If you'd prefer to stay on RadRails 2, then I suggest you just use the OS terminal/command line and run irb there.

There's nothing special we add on top, and we're moving towards pushing users to use the command line more with Rails in Studio 3. If you need to interact with your rails app in an irb session, then you'll want to run "ruby script/console" for Rails 2.x and lower, and "rails console" for Rails 3.x.

Comment: When I run irb or ruby from the Aptana Studio 3 terminal I get a "sh.exe command not found" error.